# Special charcter apears after li tag

Tags: html, css

[image]

How I can remove this special character?
This is my css:

```
.copy ul{
    display: inline-block; margin:0 0 0 15px; 
}
.copy ul li{
    display:inline; list-style:none;
}


<div class="copy"> <span>&copy; <?php echo date("Y"); ?> My Company</span>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="privacy.php" title="Privacy Policy">Privacy Policy</a></li>              
            <li><a href="email_policy.php" title="Email Policy">Email Policy</a></li>              
            <li><a href="antispampolicy.php" title="Anti Spam Policy">Anti Spam Policy</a></li>              
            <li class="last"><a href="tos.php" title="Terms & Condition">Terms & Condition</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: might help to see your html too

Comment: Looks like Unicode symbol..maybe a character which is not understood by the encoding standard.

Comment: Can you put your PhP/HTML code here? are you using php and mysql to make the menu dynamically ?? it seems it's an encoding issue

Comment: what is the `charset` of your html?

Comment: @LEO   
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's an encoding problem. Why don't you try to change your encoding type. If you have Notepad++, open your php file with it and in Format menu choose encode in utf-8 without BOM.

Comment: Can I do this in dreamviewer?

Comment: Sure. I have Dreamweaver 2014.1 and you can do this in "File>Save As>Unicode Options..." window.

Comment: I changed the encoding into uft-8, working now.